# Unable to Acces GSM modem via usb to Serial cable

Tags: windows, embedded

I am using **GSM** modem for my collage project. In my project  I try to access that **GSM** modem by using **USB-Serial** cable. My Os is **Windows 7 (32 Bit)** that ask the **prolific usb to serial adapter Driver** need to install but I install so many drivers, but I am not able to access my GSM modem via **X-CTU** (Application that I used to access my modem by **AT-commands**). My modem will return the text which I gave through **AT-commands**.

Eg; **>AT** (Command by me)

**>OK** (Modem’s reply)

**X-CTU** app show that “**prolific usb to serial adapter(Com9)**” but I used to click ‘**Test/Query**’ button it will pop-up the window that shows “**Unable to Connect**.”
Please help me...

Answer (score 0):

I hope you've not connected the RS232 interface (using +/-12V to signal) of the USB-to-serial adaptor directly to the logic-level interface of the GSM modem (using 0 and 5V or even 0 and 3.3V).  That might have broken it...

Assuming you have the right voltage levels, can you use a simpler terminal (like [Teraterm](http://ttssh2.sourceforge.jp/)) to establish a connection, to at least narrow down where the problem might be?

Can you get an oscilloscope and put a probe on the Tx and Rx lines of the serial port?